# verify BCrypt password stored in database

Tags: java, bcrypt

I working on a log in system in Java and I am using PostgreSQL. I have a registration form that saves the user information to the database. It also hashes the password before storing. I am now trying to verify the password that the user enters against the hashed password in the database.

```
try {
                //connects to the database
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cc", "pi", "server");
                //prepares SELECT statement 
                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username, user_pass FROM users WHERE username = '" + username +"';");
                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
                String upass = new String(password.getPassword());
                String user = "";
                String pass = "";
                while(result.next()){
                    user = result.getString("username");
                    pass = result.getString("user_pass");
                }
                if(username.equals(user) && BCrypt.checkpw(upass, pass)){
                    frame.dispose();
                    new CommunityCooks();
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "incorrect credentials");
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException f){
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is the section that I am trying to verify the password matches. The "password" variable is a JPasswordField and the "username" variable is a JTextField. The stored credentials are 'tester' for the username and password and I am able to verify them as local variables and fields. I think the issue I am having is with the translation of the JTextField and the JPasswordField. What I am looking for help on is getting the username and password that the user enters to verify against the stored credentials after the password is hashed from the registration form. The issue I am having is that I can run the application and the login frame opens. I enter the test credentials and it is not matching. I’m getting my incorrect credentials message. I am unclear about the syntax for comparing the stored username (not hashed) and the stored password (hashed) against the user input credentials in the JTextField and the JPasswordField. I thought what I had was correct but it appears to not be right. The testing I have done for it works to read the database and verify but it is not working when I implement it in my program. The only difference in the two is the use of the fields where the test did not use them. My test is below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstName = "tester";
        String lastName = "tester";
        String email = "tester";
        String username = "tester";
        String password = "tester";
        try {
            //connects to the database
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cc", "pi", "server");
            //inserts values into table
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            statement.setString(1, firstName);
            statement.setString(2, lastName);
            statement.setString(3, email);
            statement.setString(4, username);
            statement.setString(5, BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt()));
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username, user_pass FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "';");
            ResultSet result = st.executeQuery();
            String u = null;
            String p = null;
            while (result.next()) {
                u = result.getString("username");
                p = result.getString("user_pass");
            }
            System.out.println(u);
            System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println(BCrypt.checkpw(password, p));
        } catch(SQLException f){
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The test output works and shows the username and the hashed password and stating that it is "true" to being verified.
Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. This is my first time using a hash system.

Comment: A lot of things could go wrong in the provided sample code. As an example it doesn't just check if the password matches, but also if provided `username` matches the `user` in DB. What if no match is returned form the DB? Or if it is in different casing (`John Dow` vs `john dow`)? Ideally this method should be split into multiple smaller ones - each with a single concern, but as a start I would recommend a `breakpoint` on the first line of the method and step by step debugging to ensure that what is expected before `BCrypt.checkpw(upass, pass)` is actually valid.

Comment: There is definitely a lot of work left for this. My main goal for the question was to understand how to call and verify the credentials with BCrypt. I used breakpoints and ran it a few times and found that I was not getting the user inputs converted to strings. I ended up getting it working using `.getText()` for the username and converting the password to a `char[]` and then to a string. It works now so I can work on all of the other details. Thanks Martin. I appreciate the input and help!